# Which payload type should I send to constructor of webrtc::PayloadRouter?

Tags: c++, webrtc

I use VP8 codec and I need to send webrtc::EncodedImage. That is why I use webrtc::PayloadRouter class for that and OnEncodedImage method in it. But when I call that method I receive message that says:

```
[064:094] [14107] (rtp_sender.cc:353): Payload type 42 not registered.
[064:094] [14107] (rtp_sender.cc:395): Don't send data with unknown payload type: 42.
```

I already made a loop to send different values to constructor of PayloadRouter. The same. What should I send to the payload_type value in that class? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by registering my payload type before creating PayloadRouter class. I called RegisterVideoSendPayload(payload_number, payload_name) in RtpRtcp object, created vector of RtpRtcp and send it while creating PayloadRouter.

rtpModules.push_back(rtpRtcp);

payloadRouter = new webrtc::PayloadRouter(rtpModules,payload_number);